# What is the best strategy for optimizing aggregation queries over a long period of time/dataset in Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have some queries that look at aggregated data over a long period of time (180 days) for data that is per second (example query below). The table's hot cache is 31 days so the queries can take over a minute to return and this is not acceptable for the dashboards I want to display them on. What would be recommended optimization strategies? My thoughts so far is to either use an update policy to push the data for these tags into a separate table with a hot cache of 180 days or to use a materialized view.

```
raw_table
| where TimeStamp between (now(-180d) .. now()) and TagName in ("Tag1","Tag2")
| extend Date = startofday(TimeStamp)
| summarize Value1=max(Value) by Date,TagName
| summarize Value1=sum(Value1) by Date
| project TagName="AggregatedData",Date,Value
```

Answer (score 1):

> *My thoughts so far is to either use an update policy to push the data for these tags into a separate table with a hot cache of 180 days or to use a materialized view.*

both options you mentioned are appropriate (even a combination of both, if required)